# How to select rows programmatically based on some condition in Tabulator-Dash

Tags: javascript, python, plotly-dash, tabulator

#### Question

I have a dash application and I'm using dash_tabulator in this application. I have a modal and when the modal pops-up there is a table in the modal and the user selects the rows that she wants to work on then clicks save so just the selected rows are shown on the main page's table. Another time if the user wants to change the rows then she clicks a button and the same modal pops up so the user can select different rows. What I want is when the update modal pops-up, the rows on the main page will be preselected. So the user will not have to remember what was the old rows or if the user just wants to add another row the user should not select all the rows on the page, again. But I could not figure out how to do it.

#### Screenshots

[main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqrhm.png)
[modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd5w8.png)

#### Code

Here is a simple example of my application. I did not put all the processes explained above in this code. I just want to rows 3,4 and 5 (*rows on the main table*) will be preselected when the modal opens.

```
    import dash_tabulator
    import dash
    from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
    import dash_html_components as html
    import dash_core_components as dcc
    from dash_extensions.javascript import Namespace
    import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
    
    
    # bootstrap css
    external_stylesheets = ['https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css']
    
    app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
    ns = Namespace("myNamespace", "tabulator")
    
    
    columns = [
        {"formatter":"rowSelection", "width": 10, "headerSort":False, "cellClick": ns("cellClick")},
        { "title": "Name", "field": "name"},
        { "title": "Age", "field": "age"}
    ]
    
    # Setup some data
    data = [
        {"id":3, "name":"Christine Lobowski", "age":"42"},
        {"id":4, "name":"Brendon Philips", "age":"125"},
        {"id":5, "name":"Margret Marmajuke", "age":"16"},
    ]
    
    
    modal_data = [
        {"id":1, "name":"Oli Bob", "age":"12"},
        {"id":2, "name":"Mary May", "age":"1"},
        {"id":3, "name":"Christine Lobowski", "age":"42"},
        {"id":4, "name":"Brendon Philips", "age":"125"},
        {"id":5, "name":"Margret Marmajuke", "age":"16"},
        {"id":6, "name":"Fred Savage", "age":"16"},
    ]
    
    options = {"selectable":"true"}
    
    
    
    app.layout = html.Div(
        [
            dbc.Modal(
                [
                    dbc.ModalBody(
                        [
                            dash_tabulator.DashTabulator(
                                id='modal-table',
                                columns=columns,
                                data=modal_data,
                                options=options
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                ],
                id="modal",
                is_open=False,
                scrollable=False,
            ),
            dbc.Button("Open Modal", id = "open-modal-button"),
            dash_tabulator.DashTabulator(
                id='table',
                columns=columns,
                data=data,
                options=options
            ),
        ]
    )
    
    @app.callback(
        Output("modal", "is_open"),
        Input("open-modal-button", "n_clicks")
    )
    def open_modal(n_clicks):
        if n_clicks:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Here is the javascript code to fire cellClick callback:

```
    window.myNamespace = Object.assign({}, window.myNamespace, {
        tabulator: {
            cellClick: function(e, cell) {
                cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
            },
        }
    });
```

#### Solution Ideas

First of all, I tried to find a property of this dash_tabulator object for selected rows to select or deselect rows in python code. There is multiRowsClicked property but changing this is not reflected on the tickbox. I could not find a way to do this in python.

Then I thought maybe I could do it in the javascript code. But first I need to get the table object. In [tabulator documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/options#find-table) there is a way to get the table object from id with this line of code:

```
    var table = Tabulator.prototype.findTable("#example-table")[0]; // find table object for table with id of example-table
```

but to use this line of code I need to import the Tabulator library into my javascript code and I could not achieve it either. I tried to install tabulator.js into my project by npm and imported Tabulator at the top of my javascript code:

```
    var Tabulator = require('tabulator-tables');
```

But then the tables were not showing up and there was another weird error. Here is the screenshot:
[tabulator-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOdkO.png)

I tried to access tabulator directly from the UNPKG CDN servers by adding assets_external_path to dash constructor by this line of code:

```
    app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets, assets_external_path="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.9.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js")
```

But again same error happened. So is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: This is too broad a question, If you are looking for help with a specific action then please ask that, but this question is essentially asking for a full guide to achieving several complex actions